# How can I fix the excel formula?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet with 20 workers that I need to fill up with worked days.
In this spreadsheet when I put “S” will count a day worked and when complete 14 consecutive days, he will received a free day.
But, when I put “P” the count back to 0 and restart the count.
Furthermore, I need too that the 14 consecutive days continues in another spreadsheet because I use this monthly.
I can’t shows in a picture cause it’s too heavy.
In this spreadsheet the names is in column “F” and line “5-25”.
I use to put worked days in column “H-AL” and line “5-25”.

In this case I tried to use “If”, but it doesn’t do correctly after the “P”, because it shows up both, the last with total counts and the another with new count, but do correctly only in the next case.

I used this:

=IF(K3="p";SOMA(CONT.SE($A$3:K3;">0"))*0;"")IF(K3="f";SOMA(CONT.IF($A$3:K3;"S"));"")&IF(K3="s";SOMA(CONT.IF($A$3:K3;"s"));"")&IF(L3="x";"";"")

In above case, I changed the lines and column only to try without broke the formula and spreadsheet, but the idea is the same.
More, in above case have X and F that means no work day.

Comment: Pls. read this topic about SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question and describe your issue more detailed give some examples and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I changed. Is more clear?